# Sort a list from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel file that contains the following entry like:

```py
A 10
B 30
C 20
A 20
B 15
```

Using python scripting how can I get the desired output, like the sum of all the similar values :

```py
A 30
B 45
C 20
```

Comment: how abt a dictionary?

Comment: What type of file are you talking about? .txt? is a dictionary? Please edit your question more precisely to give us more understanding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
d = dict()
for letter, number in line:
  d[letter] = number + d.get(letter, 0)

for x in sorted(d.keys()):
  print(x, d[x])
```

The second param in `d.get` gives a default value of `0` if `letter` is not already in the dictionary.

The `sorted()` func makes sure you are going in incr order wrt to keys.

We have a cumulative mapping and then print it out, short and sweet :)